# Data frame as selection criteria

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, selection, criteria

Is there a way to use one data frame with x headers each containing 1 value as selection criteria for another larger set of data?

For example:

```
VH <- na.omit(data_frame[data_frame$distance>=1000 & data_frame$distance<=4000 & data_frame$corde==conditions_course$hippo_corde, c("date_course","handicap.1","distance","corde","nb_part","classement","nom_cheval")])
> VH
    date_course handicap.1 distance corde nb_part classement     nom_cheval
11   2015-07-25         56     3600     D      17          4        Bushido
16   2015-07-25         56     3600     D      17          5        Ami Sol
32   2015-07-30         55     3700     D      12          8   Pourtoimarco
33   2015-07-10         53     3400     D       9          1   Pourtoimarco
56   2015-07-25         61     3600     D      17          2 Vicomte dAnjou
57   2015-06-30         58     3400     D      17          1 Vicomte dAnjou
73   2015-07-25         59     3600     D      17          3     Besnardine
74   2015-06-30         59     3400     D      17          2     Besnardine
100  2015-07-30         56     3700     D      12          7       Bénuisca
```

I can keep adding `data_frame$corde==conditions_course$hippo_corde` the matching criteria but aside from not being elegant, it calls for human intervention whereas defining the criteria and their values in a csv file could automate that part of the data selection.

Edited from here on
I have placed a file here: http://we.tl/c7gcv5BO9K
That file contains past performances of horses. There is another file named infocourse.csv that contains the same headers with just one row of values representing any day's racing condition.
The objective is to "find" in 20 starters (for example) each having 20 performances, the races which are most relevant to the racing conditions.
distance (+/- 200)
corde (exact match)
libel_hippo (exact)
ssp (exact)

Here is what I have done, and I'm just asking if there is a more generic way of setting this up.

```
#I first read all csv of starters
file_names <-list.files(pattern = "\\d")
data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv,header=TRUE, sep = ";"))
#then I convert certain fields so they can be matched
data_frame$date_course <- as.Date(data_frame$date_course, "%d/%m/%Y")
data_frame$corde <- as.character(data_frame$corde)
#then this is the part that I'd like to make more customizable
pertinent_RKM<-na.omit(data_frame[data_frame$distance>=2600 & data_frame$distance<=3400 & data_frame$date_course>="2015-06-01" & data_frame$date_course<="2015-09-01", c("date_course","libel_hippo","redkm","distance","nom_cheval","classement","nb_part")])
bestRKM<-aggregate(redkm ~ nom_cheval, pertinent_RKM, mean)
bestRKMtrie<-bestRKM[with(bestRKM, order(redkm)),]
```

Hope this is clearer. It has been simplified for the purpose of discussion as the data sets and condition variables are larger in real life.
Thank you for this great site and community!

Comment: Give us some data to play with

Comment: ok I'll set it up better although I wanted a generic example..it will take me a few days...

Comment: Also for producing a "generic answer" one needs to know what your raw material is, and how the result is expected to look like. I can't read that from your question. Happy to give it a shot, but ... data ... ;-)